# MVC shows the htmlcode inside my webpage that is created by tiny mce

Tags: html, model-view-controller, tinymce-4, fckeditor

I am using tiny mce (a kind of editor like fckeditor ) .so i use that to get my news content .

when i save the content of tiny mce textbox something like this is saved to the database :

```
&lt;p&gt;this is a test&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;good luck&lt;/p&gt;
```

I use the `@html.raw(newstext)` .But the browser shows this :

[image]

best regards.

Comment: Try this: `@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(newstext))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content is stored in your database as encoded HTML so to display it you need to decode. So this should work:

```
@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(newstext))
```

Or you can most likely drop the `Raw` method too and just go with:

```
@HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(newstext)
```